# Can I make a turtle search patches within some distance range?

Tags: netlogo

I want a turtle to search for the nearest patch that outside of its home that has a certain color.

In this case, I want a duck, that is in its pond, to go to another pond. For this I have.

```
ask Anas-discors [ifelse distance my-home < 5 [set my-home one-of patches with [pcolor = 88 and distance > 5 and min [distance]] fd 1 set energy energy - 30 ][face mi-casa fd 1 set energy energy - 30]]
```

I know the problem is with that last part in the `min [distance]`, however, I've been unable to fix it and the ducks are not flying

Comment: I'm going to refer you to the `distance` entry in the netlogo users manual. It tells you pretty much everything that you need

Comment: You probably need the `in-radius` primitive. Here's a link on how to use it: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/bind/primitive/in-radius.html

Comment: How would in-radius be used here? Im thought distance to be the one

Comment: `in-radius` will not be very helpful. `in-radius` gives you an agentset of all agents within a certain range, but the question here is how to get the one agent that is closest.
For that you will want to combine `min-one-of` and `distance`. The dictionary entrance for `distance` gives you a good example of the combination.

Comment: Yup. Seems like I misread the question. Sorry. `in-radius` is definitely not relevant in this case and @LeirsW 's comment is accurate.

Comment: @Leirs and umit1010 thanks! I found a post where someone used distance and, although it was for something different, i saw that the key was in using parenthesis, not brakets. the final code it this:
ask Anas-discors [ifelse distance mi-casa < 5 [set mi-casa min-one-of (patches with [(pcolor = 88 )]) [distance myself] fd 1 set energia energia - 30 ][face mi-casa fd 1 set energia energia - 30]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@bksnlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13535067/bksnlow) has already concluded, the solution is in enforcing the `patches with[]` to self-evaluate their own `[distance]` property from each of the herd of the respectively `ask`-ed Duck ( `myself` )-cases

Enjoy the ride :

```
ask Anas-discors [
    ifelse distance mi-casa < 5 [ ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; IF  : Duck is close to home pond
                                  set mi-casa              ;     SET mi-casa become
                                  min-one-of (             ;         the closest patch
                                      patches with [       ;         with all of these
                                            ( pcolor = 88 );              ( propertyA ) and
                                            ;...           ;              ( ... )
                                            ]              ;         ordered by their
                                      ) [ distance myself ];         distance from Ana
                                ; fd 1                     ; <-- same as if not < 5
                                ; set energia energia - 30 ; <-- same as if not < 5
                                  ]
                                [ ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ELSE: Duck is far from home pond
                                  face mi-casa             ;     TURN Duck towards mi-casa
                                ; fd 1                     ; <-- same as if was < 5
                                ; set energia energia - 30 ; <-- same as if was < 5
                                  ]
    fd 1                                                   ; FORWARD 1 step
    set energia energia - 30                               ; SET      -energy spent
    ]
```

Good flight, Ducks!

A nice case of *ABM* simulation